# How to add custom views display formats to a view?

Tags: views

I have a project in which some views have different displays. I want to create similar displays for other views, see in the image. Can I reuse them or I will have to do custom coding again for each view?[image: views custom display formats]

Comment: You could simply export the view and then import choosing to give it a unique name in the process. Then you have the same view as a jump off point for your newly imported view.

Comment: I can't see any export option for the view. Should I download and enable the views_data_export module?

Comment: Look in the contextual menus within a view or on the main views page, no need for an extra module.

Answer (score 1):

further to what @Danny Englander says, you can find the export option for a view to the right of the display list:

[image]